# Stuck in History #2

Tags: riddle, history

We have been living a normal life for a while
Searching for necessities at every mile
But with the spread of a new invention
A more calm life springs into action

What historical event is this alluding to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been living a normal life for a while

> Hunting and gathering was the normal mode of existence for all humans for over 180,000 years.

Searching for necessities at every mile

> This life involved obtaining food by foraging - searching for food in the wild. Most tribes were nomadic, as this lifestyle would deplete a certain area of useful food in time.

But with the spread of a new invention

> [Agriculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neolithic_Revolution) first appeared at least as far back as 11,700 years ago, and farming groups quickly displaced hunter-gatherers nearly everywhere.

A more calm life springs into action

> Agricultural peoples tend to stay in the same place and have a routine, relatively uneventful life compared to hunter-gatherers.

What historical event is this alluding to?

> The neolithic revolution